# How common is it to use the present tense when speaking of deceased persons?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In my native language (not English) it is customary to use the past tense when speaking of properties and (posthumous) actions of deceased persons.

But in English, I occasionally encounter statements like: "[A. A. Milne] **is** the father of bookseller Christopher Robin Milne [...]" (from the Wikipedia article on A. A. Milne; my emphasis). Both A. A. Milne and his son are no longer with us, by the way.

Is this standard practice, an idiosyncrasy of certain writers, or simply a common error? In any case, the present tense for dead people mildly irritates me, but perhaps that's unreasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you describe actions of the person, you would always use the past tense. E.g.

> A. A. Milne **wrote** *Winnie the Pooh*.

But relationships can be described in either the past or present tense. The relationship between a parent and child is eternal -- A. A. Milne was and always will be Christopher RObin Milne's father.

Similarly, you can say

> A. A. Milne **is** the author of *Winnie the Pooh*.

No one else became the author when he died, so he's still the author.

I think the choice in these cases is simply personal style. Past tense sounds more natural to me.